# Apache Ignite 2.9.0 Recover from lost partitions

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ignite, partition

We have setup a apache ignite 2.9.0 cluster with native persistence using kubernetes in Azure with 4 nodes. To update some cache configuration, we restarted all the ignite nodes. After restart, running any sql query on one particular table - results in restart of 2 ignite nodes and after that we see lost partitions exception.

If we try to restart all nodes to recover from lost partitions, then its fine until we run any sql query on that table after which 2 nodes restart and we get lost partitions exception.
Is there anyway we can recover from  lost partitions and overcome this problem? We also wanted to understand  why its occuring?We could not find any logs related to this.

Answer (score 3):

When all partition owners left the grid, the partition is considered to be lost, you might think of this as a special internal marker. Depending on the PartitionLossPolicy Ignite might ignore this fact and allow cache operations or disallow them to protect data consistency.

If you use native persistence, then most likely there was no physical data loss and all you need is to tell Ignite that you are aware of the situation, now all data are in place and it's safe to remove the "lost" mark from the partitions.

I think the most simple way to handle this would be to use the control script from within a pod:

```
control.sh --cache reset_lost_partitions cacheName1,cacheName2,...
```

More details:
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/partition-loss-policy#handling-partition-loss

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I forgot to mention that I tried this earlier and now as well but still I am getting the lost partition exception